# How to stop a time function nested in a function?

Tags: javascript, function, web-applications, setinterval

I was able to get the following code from some class work I'm working on. It works really well for what I need it for and I like that I can call `startTime();` to start it. However, I'm now at a point where I need to figure out how to stop it.  Is there a way to do `startTime(stop);` or something similar?

```
function startTime() {
    let hours = 0;
    let minutes = 0;
    let seconds = 0;
    const timer = setInterval(function () {
        seconds++;
        if (seconds === 60) {
            minutes++;
            seconds = 0;
        }
        second.innerHTML = formatTime();
    }, 1000);
    function formatTime() {
        let sec = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds) : '0' + String(seconds);
        let min = seconds > 9 ? String(minutes) : '0' + String(minutes);
        return min + ':' + sec;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to scope the variable that the `setInterval` is assigned to *outside* of `startTime`, so that it can be accessed and have `clearInterval` called on it externally. For example, this snippet will assign an interval to the `timer`, and then clear the interval after 5 seconds:

```js
let timer;
function startTime() {
    let hours = 0;
    let minutes = 0;
    let seconds = 0;
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        seconds++;
        if (seconds === 60) {
            minutes++;
            seconds = 0;
        }
        second.innerHTML = formatTime();
    }, 1000);
    function formatTime() {
        let sec = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds) : '0' + String(seconds);
        let min = seconds > 9 ? String(minutes) : '0' + String(minutes);
        return min + ':' + sec;
    }
}
function stopTime() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}
startTime();
setTimeout(stopTime, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="second"></div>
```

Comment: That makes sense, I'll play around with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd prefer using a class to keep track of `setInterval`'s return value.

```
class Timer {
  constructor(callback) {
    this.minutes = 0
    this.seconds = 0

    this.timer = null
    this.callback = callback
  }

  start() {
    // Make sure the timer isn't already running!
    if (this.timer !== null) {
      return
    }

    // Execute the callback every second, passing in
    // the new number of minutes and seconds
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.seconds++
      if (this.seconds === 60) {
        this.minutes++
        this.seconds = 0
      }
      this.callback(this.minutes, this.seconds)
    }, 1000)
  }

  stop() {
    clearInterval(timer)
    this.timer = null
  }
}

const timer = new Timer((minutes, seconds)) => {
  const sec = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds) : '0' + String(seconds)
  const min = seconds > 9 ? String(minutes) : '0' + String(minutes)
  const formatted = min + ':' + sec

  second.innerHTML = formatted
})

timer.start() // start the timer
timer.stop()  // stop the timer
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just return the timer from the function to the caller. Then the caller can use it however it wants:

```js
function startTime() {
    let hours = 0;
    let minutes = 0;
    let seconds = 0;
    function formatTime() {
        let sec = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds) : '0' + String(seconds);
        let min = seconds > 9 ? String(minutes) : '0' + String(minutes);
        return min + ':' + sec;
    }
    
    // return this value to the caller so they can stop it
    return setInterval(function () {
        seconds++;
        if (seconds === 60) {
            minutes++;
            seconds = 0;
        }
        console.log(formatTime());
    }, 1000);
    
}
// receives the result of setTimout
let timerControl = startTime()

// stop it after a few seconds
setTimeout(()=> {
  clearTimeout(timerControl)
  console.log("Stopped")
 }, 4000)
```